If I disallow any inbound traffic to my pod by using k8s network policy, will the k8s api-server still be able to reach it?
Say, I have something like this:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-ingress-to-festiv-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
        app: festiv
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress

Will the k8s api-server still be able to reach my app: festiv labeled pod, if its use case is to extend the k8s api-server by leveraging its aggregation layer and is registered as an APIService?
What will the "decision" depend on? Is it how one sets up the api-server itself? Is it based on CNI plugin used? etc

See this answer, also this is a great tool to manage network policies

You will need to add the IP address of the API server, taken from this answer.
Use this tool to create and check network policies, and this tool to caculate CIDR blocks.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-ingress-to-festiv-app
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
  ingress:
    - from:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 34.76.197.27/32
  egress: []

See here

Isn't that for enabling my app: festiv pod to call the api-server and not the other way around (i.e. k8s api-server calling app: festiv pod)? I am actually playing around on a k8s cluster and can see that even though I have disallowed any ingress traffic, api-server seems to be able to reach out to my pod but was curious whether there are nuances to that.

@festiv I've updated the example, use the tool it makes it simple.
